# Filing Bootstrap Datatable from remote JSON file

Tags: json, datatables, cors

I am trying to fill the table (Bootstrap datatable) with the data from remote JSON file.

JSON file is located at https://ba.ekapija.com/company/tender-winner-json/103510/pobede-na-tenderima?hash=28cd4a0e334aec8f84a94f30bb340e7f

And this is the function I use:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#twodotsmediatable').dataTable( {
    "data": "https://ba.ekapija.com/company/tender-winner-json/103510/pobede-na-tenderima?hash=28cd4a0e334aec8f84a94f30bb340e7f",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "tender" },
            { "data": "url" },
            { "data": "date" },
            { "data": "amount" },
            { "data": "company" },
            { "data": "address" }
        ]
  } );

  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});
```

I have also tried with:

```
"ajax": "https://ba.ekapija.com/company/tender-winner-json/103510/pobede-na-tenderima?hash=28cd4a0e334aec8f84a94f30bb340e7f"
```

But with no luck in both cases. Please help me to find where am I making mistake.

Comment: I'm getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ba.ekapija.com/company/tender-winner-json/103510/pobede-na-tenderima?hash=28cd4a0e334aec8f84a94f30bb340e7f&_=1551280803293. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)". is your datatable on the same server as the above json?

Comment: @shubham No it is not, it is on remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `ajax.url` :

```js
$('#twodotsmediatable').dataTable( {
  ajax: {
    url: 'https://ba.ekapija....'
  },
  columns: [ .. ]
})
```

You cannot overcome request blocking in the browser, but you can get the desired JSON through a serverside proxy. If your server support PHP a `proxy.php` could look like this :

```php
<?
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url']);
?>
```

Get data via proxy :

```js
$('#twodotsmediatable').dataTable( {
  ajax: {
    url: 'proxy.php?url=https://ba.ekapija....',
    dataSrc: function(d) {
      return d[0];
    }
  },
  columns: [ .. ]
})
```

**NB**: Use of `dataSrc` is needed since the JSON seem to be on the form `[[{ item, item, .. } ]]`

Comment: If I understood you well my script function should now look like this - https://jsfiddle.net/twodotsmedia/mzhq0nyv/1/
With php file generated in php folder named proxy.php with lines you have added. But not the data shown in datatable yet :(

Comment: @MladenM., Yes - if you not get any result, then the path is incorrect. The path should be relative, `proxy.php?url=` if proxy is in root (or the same location as the running script) look under the Network tab in the console to see what error messages you get, probably a **404** ...